# socket.io frames data not readable in chrome devtools

Tags: websocket, socket.io, google-chrome-devtools

Server :

```
function startServer() {
  const io = new Server().attach(8090);

  io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    console.log("connection on server");
    socket.emit('test','test data');
  });
}
```

Client :

```
const socket = io(`${location.protocol}//${location.hostname}:8090`);
socket.on('test', (data) => {
  console.log(data);
})
```

Then :

- I start the server
- I open the client code

Server log output :

```
connection on server
```

Client console output :

```
test data
```

So all looks good, but when I open the websocket panel on chrome devtools i see this : 
[image: dev tools output]

I cannot find the websocket data in the frames : only the "probe" thing and numbers.

**How can I see frames data ?**

Using https://www.websocket.org/echo.html I can perfectly read data in the frames : 
[image: websocket echo WS devtool panel]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `2probe` and random numbers you are seeing in the Frames panel is the Packet Type, followed by a ping/pong between client and server. You can read the details [here](https://github.com/socketio/engine.io-protocol/blob/master/README.md#packet).

You can only view data in the Frames panel if you are **broadcasting** messages from the server. In your case, you are sending a message with data to the client connected and handling it in a callback. If you want both yourself and all other clients to see the data, use:

```
io.sockets.emit('test', 'test data');
```

If two client connections are made to the server, both will receive `test data`, when the event is handled with the `test` event on the client. When the second client connects, you will see the message in the Frames panel. You don't see it for your own connection.

If you want to only broadcast that message to all other client, but not yourself, use:

```
socket.broadcast.emit('test','test data');
```

You can see some more information in [chrome://net-internals/](http://chrome://net-internals/), indicating the data being sent, though it doesn't show you the actual text content unless you have a network sniffing tool like [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) or [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler).

[image: net internals]